# Efficient storage and calling of varying objects

Tags: c++

This question deals with the ability to construct a structure that is able to be easily iterated through.

The problem:

I have four different "boxes":

- Box A: Always has 1 apple and 1 pear
- Box B: Always has 1 orange and 1 pear
- Box C: Always has 1 peach
- Box D: Can have varying amounts of apples and oranges (0 - 10+) but always has 1 pear

Each piece of fruit has a different taste value

I currently process this information by creating a queue of the different taste values and box types then process this information with a lots of if-elses in multiple functions.

Here is an example of one function that seeks to get a total sum of the taste values e.g.

```
void process_crate(vector<string> boxes, vector<double> taste_value, vector<vector<double> > amount){

    unsigned int count = 0; // holds index in taste_value
    double sum_taste = 0;  // holds taste value 

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++){
        string active_box = boxes[i];

        if(active_box == "A"){ // An apple and a pear

            sum_taste += taste_box_A(taste_value[count],taste_value[count+1]); // user preference

            count += 2;
        }else if(active_box == "B"){ // An orange and a pear
            sum_taste += taste_box_B(taste_value[count], taste_value[count+1]); // user preference

            count += 2;
        }else if(active_box == "C"){ // A peach
            sum_taste += taste_box_C(taste_value[count], taste_value[count+1]); // user preference

            count += 1;
        }else{ // Box D varying apples and oranges, but always a pear

            unsigned int apples = amount[i][0];
            unsigned int oranges = amount[i][1];

            vector<double> apple_tastes(apples);
            vector<double> orange_tastes(oranges);

            double pear_taste = taste_value[count+apples + oranges];

            if(apples != 0){
                for(unsigned int j = 0; j<apples; j++){
                    apple_tastes[j] = taste_value[count+j];
                }
                count += apples;
            }

            if(oranges != 0){
                for(unsigned int j = 0; j<apples; j++){
                    orange_tastes[j] = taste_value[count+j];
                }
                count += oranges;
            }

            sum_taste += taste_box_D(apple_tastes, orange_tastes, pear_taste); // user preference
            count += 1;
        }

    }
}
```

I think use of IF-ELSE statements combined with lots of vectors to store the data could be greatly improved.

Any suggestions?

Comment: look up virtual functions

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is that you're doing with these boxes/constructs. Would you say that the output of the processing is just the `sum_taste` and the `count`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to know where to start with this, but here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### When seeking a review, provide full code

The posted code is just a fragment with a lot of pieces missing.  For instance, all of the `taste_box_x` functions are missing and it's not really very obvious what they might be.  To get a better review, post a better question.

### Pass complex types reference rather than by value

For complex types such as `std::vector`, it's usually better to pass by reference rather than by value to avoid forcing each function call to make copies.  If the passed object should not be modified by the routine, pass a `const` reference.

### Use classes

Since this is C++, it would make sense to use classes.  For example, one could imagine that there is a base class `box` from which each of the box types might be derived.  User taste preference could be an `std::unordered_set` in which each fruit type is the key and the value would be that user's taste weighting value.  Fruits might be an `enum class`, etc.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.